# Angularjs state resolve before controller

Tags: angularjs

I know this question gets asked a lot, and I have read a bunch of stackoverflow questions on this topic but nothing I do seems to fix my issue. Please help show me how I am being an idiot.

Using angular 1.3.0.

Here is my state:

```
.state('app.admin.cards.edit', {
  url: '/edit/:cardID',
  views: {
    cards: {
      templateUrl: 'tpl/cards.edit.html',
      controller: 'AdminCardEditCtrl',
      resolve: {
        data: ['$stateParams', 'AdminCardService',
          function ($stateParams, AdminCardService) {
            var cardID = $stateParams.cardID;
            AdminCardService.getCard(cardID).then(function (data) {
              return data;
            });
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  access: { auth: true, admin: true }
})
```

Here is my controller:

```
.controller('AdminCardEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 'AdminCardService', 'data', 
  function ($scope, $window, AdminCardService, data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Here is part of my service:

```
.factory('AdminCardService', function ($http, $q) {
  return {
    ...
    getCard: function (_id) {
      var d = $q.defer();
      var promise = $http.post('/api/card', { _id: _id }).success(function (data) {
        d.resolve(data);
      });
      return d.promise;
    },
    ...
  };
});
```

The data never gets passed to the controller and the console.log just outputs "undefined". If I console.log the data in the state or in the service, it is all working as expected. What am I doing wrong people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the result of AdminCardService in your router.  The router will handle the 'then' callback and send the result of that to your controller:

```
resolve: {
        data: ['$stateParams', 'AdminCardService',
          function ($stateParams, AdminCardService) {
            var cardID = $stateParams.cardID;
            return AdminCardService.getCard(cardID);;
          }
        ]
      }
```